# How close is a given graph to a star?

Tags: graph-theory

Working as a bioinformatician on biological graph embedding, I often have to manually figure out how much a graph looks like a star, or how I imprecisely refer to it, the *starryness of a graph*, because even though there are sometimes true graphs with high centrality nodes more often this is just caused by sampling bias (e.g. the team providing the data has only executed experiments against one specific gene).

For this reason, I believe that a metric that determines how much a graph looks like a composition of (one or more) stars may be of importance in the context of capturing sampling biases in newly generated datasets.

Now, an obvious solution may be the [KL Divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) between the sorted degrees distribution of a graph with $N$ nodes and max degree $d_{\text{MAX}}$ and the star with the same number of nodes and the central node with the same degree. This definition could be easily extended to a graph with multiple components, by averaging out the score of each component, maybe weighting it by the number of nodes in each component.

This solution seems easy to compute, but it quickly loses meaning if the graph is composed of multiple connected starts, a case that is quite common in biased data. For this second case, one may select the top 1 percentile of the degrees for instance, and locally compute how starry (according to the KL Divergence-based score described above) these subgraphs are when compared to some other random sub-samples of the graphs.

Do you have other ideas? Do you know of some papers dealing with this issue?

Thanks!